# Base64 Encoding and decoding does not work

Tags: c#, encoding, base64, decoding

I watched a lot of tutorials everywhere and they all say it should work but it doesnt.

I want to enter "*encode RandomText*" and then it should encode the "*RandomText*" to Base64 and if I type "*decode [theEncodedText]*" it should decode from the Base64 and give me "*RandomText*". I did everything I could do but it still doesn't work.

Check my full code:

```
    static public void Write(string text, int ms)
    {
        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(ms);
            Console.Write(c);
        }
    }
    static public string Encode(string text)
    {
        byte[] encodedBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encodedBytes);
    }
    static public string Decode(string text)
    {
        byte[] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(text2);
        return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(decodedBytes);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "";
        while (input != "exit")
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Write("Input:> ", 10); Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower().Trim();

            if (input.StartsWith("encode"))
            {
                try
                {
                    string toEncode = input.Substring(7);
                    Write(Encode(toEncode) + "\n\n", 10);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Write("Please enter the text to encode!\n\n", 10);
                }
            }
            else if (input.StartsWith("decode"))
            {
                try
                {
                    string toDecode = input.Substring(7);
                    Write(Decode(toDecode) + "\n\n", 10);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Write("The entered text is either missing or is not encoded!\n\n", 10);
                }                  
            }
            else
            {
                if (input != "" && input != "exit")
                {
                    Write("Invalid command.\n\n", 10);
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base64 is case sensitive. You're lowering the case on your input data. Therefore it won't work.